# Excluding an item in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to find the total size of a root directory on an FTP server. However, I do not have access to one of the directories in the root.

I want to use this function to sum the sizes of the directories in the root:

```
size = 0
for filename in ftp.nlst("."):
    ftp.cwd(filename)
    size += ftp.size(".")    
print(size)
```

This generates the error:

```
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Could not get file size.
```

I can't find any documentation about excluding an item from a for loop.

Comment: I assume by error you mean exception. Just wrap it in a `try: except` and `continue` on the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just catch the exception and `pass` or `continue`, e.g.:

```
for filename in ftp.nlst("."):
    try:
        ftp.cwd(filename)
        size += ftp.size(".")    
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        pass
print(size)
```